# How can I use Lagrangian Multipliers to maximize a General Rayleigh Quotient for Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm reading up on Linear Discriminant Analysis and have hit the point where one wants to maximize:

$$
\frac{v^{T}S_{b}v}{v^{T}S_{w}v}
$$

with respect to $v$, where $S_b$ is the between class variance matrix, $S_w$ is the within class variance matrix and $v$ is an arbitrary unit vector. I want to find the value of $v$ that maximizes the above ratio. I know there are other ways to do this, but I want to do this using Lagrangian multipliers.

So, I set

$$
L = \frac{v^{T}S_{b}v}{v^{T}S_{w}v} - \lambda (v^{T}v - 1)
$$

Now, concentrating on the derivative with respect to $v$, I get

$$
\frac{[2S_{b}v (v^{T}S_{w}v) - (v^{T}S_{b}v) (2S_{w}v)]}{(v^{T}S_{w}v)^{2}} - 2\lambda v = 0
$$

At this point, I can factor out $2v$, giving me

$$
\left(\frac{S_{b} (v^{T}S_{w}v) - (v^{T}S_{b}v) S_{w}}{(v^{T}S_{w}v)^{2}} - \lambda I \right) v = 0
$$

But, now I'm stuck. How do I get to

$$
S_{w}^{-1}S_{b}v = \lambda v  ???
$$

PS - I'm now also confused by the fact that when I factored out $v$, I ended up subtracting a scalar (i.e. $\lambda$) from a matrix ??? (Note: This is no longer issue. A comment showed me my oversight there)

Comment: You would want $\lambda I$ there, I think.

Comment: Lagrange Multipliers are unnecessary: $\:v^2$ appears in both the denominator and the numerator, so the constraint is inoperative.  Instead, calculate the gradient of the **unconstrained** problem and set it to zero.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: For the unconstrained problem I get $\left(v^T S_b v \right)S_w=\left(v^TS_w v\right) S_b$ but I cannot see you can solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First massage the nominator of your formula by expanding a few identity matrices as $I = S_wS_w^{-1}$ to make the term $S_w^{-1}S_bv$ appear:
$$
\Big(S_b(v^TS_wv) - S_w(v^TS_bv)\Big)v = S_w\Big(S_w^{-1}S_b(v^TS_wv)-I(v^TS_wS_w^{-1}S_bv)\Big)v
= S_w\Big((S_w^{-1}S_bv)(v^TS_wv) - v\big(v^TS_w(S_w^{-1}S_bv)\big)\Big)
$$
And then notice that it is equal to zero if $S_w^{-1}S_bv = \mu \, v$ for some scalar $\mu$. I deliberately did not use $\lambda$ here, as others pointed out in the comment, the constraint and its Lagrange multiplier is "inoperative", hence $\lambda = 0$. The solution to your problem is the eigenvector of the matrix $S_w^{-1}S_b$ which corresponds to the largest eigenvalue $\mu$. The maximum value is also $\mu$, which you can see by using $I = S_wS_w^{-1}$ and
$$
\frac{v^TS_bv}{v^TS_wv} = \frac{v^TS_w(S_w^{-1}S_bv)}{v^TS_wv} = \mu .
$$